# How do I set name for curve?

Tags: c++, qt, qcustomplot

I use `QCPCurve` to draw. When I try to set name for the curve to display on screen, it doesn't work

I code on Qt Creater 4.6.2 based on Qt 5.11.1 , Linux Ubuntu 4.15.0-20-generic:

```
mCurveRoute = new QCPCurve(mCustomPlot->xAxis, mCustomPlot->yAxis);
mCurveRoute->setPen(QPen(Qt::red))
mCurveRoute->setName("Route");
```

Name of `Curve` hasn't displayed without no error messages.

Comment: Sounds like the desirable behaviour can be achieved through the Plot Legend (QCPLegend), which each QCustomPlot has a QCPLegend.

Comment: Yeah, i set visible for legend and it was displayed,.